# I have a code that is running perfectly in the python idle but it is not running in the terminal correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main(): 
     name = input('Typer your name and press enter: ')
     name_list = name.split()

     print(name_list)

     first = name_list[0][0]
     middle = name_list[1][0]
     last = name_list[2][0]

     print(first.upper(),'.', middle.upper(),'.', last.upper()) 

main()
```

I am using python 3.5.2

Comment: the name_list is on the third line and name is also indented like the others.

Comment: are you getting any errors or terminal response? You need to change `def main()` to `def main():`

Comment: I do have the def main (): I forgot to put it on here. I am getting an invalid syntax for the middle name everytime I run it in terminal

Comment: It will fail for any name that doesn't have one of those names and not display any names longer than 3. But other than that it works just fine in terminal that I can see. Please let us know how you are executing it in terminal and exactly what the errors is.

Comment: I entered ang go koms as the name when it ran. It says invalid syntax under the o in go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the code in Python 2, not Python 3... Observe

```
$ python script.py
Typer your name and press enter: ang go koms
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "script.py", line 2, in main
    name = input('Typer your name and press enter: ')
  File "<string>", line 1
    ang go koms
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Hence, your "error". Lookup the difference in `input` vs. `raw_input`... It's a common problem.

---

Now, try Python3

```
$ python3 script.py
Typer your name and press enter: ang go koms
['ang', 'go', 'koms']
A . G . K
```

You can see that my default `python` is actually Python 2

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help!

Comment: I see the difference in the input vs raw_input. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any particular issue with the code you put up other than the missing colon. So this is what I have that run successfully. It seems you didn't copy paste the code you are running since you said you have the colon in your code. So maybe try mine and see if there is a difference somewhere character wise.

```
def main():
    name = input('Type your name and press enter: ')
    name_list = name.split()

    print(name_list)

    first = name_list[0][0]
    middle = name_list[1][0]
    last = name_list[2][0]

    print(first.upper(), '.', middle.upper(), '.', last.upper())

main()
```

You may also want to look at handling when a name is longer or shorter than 3 words.

Comment: It still will not run properly in my terminal. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by terminal? Are you meaning you are executing the python file with command 'python python_file.py' in a terminal of the operating system?